# Displace Modifier: reset scale problem

Tags: modeling, modifiers

**HERE THE FILE**

[image]

This is my tunnel with all my stats . . . I had a sub surface and the displace with CLOUDS.

[image]

I want to import this model in Unity and I have to change the metric then I click on scene and modify the general scale from 1 to 0.01. After that, I scale my mesh in order to bring it back to correct measures. Now the situation is this

[image]

My mesh has the scale settings (100 100 100).

In oder to reset the scale to (1 1 1) I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>Scale</kbd>. The displace disappears cause the new scale:

[image]
The only way to bring it back is to increase the value of the strenght (from 0.2 to 20) in the displace, and i did it but the result is this below:

[image]

**The problem is this: It's completly different from the initial result i had before! Take a look**

[image]

**It's look like denser, and sharper . . . How can I fix it? What could be my error in this workflow?**

Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem in your scene, it's just that you need to multiply the size of your texture by 100 not by 10, idem for the strength

Comment: Yeah . . . this is so true XD My bad . . . it was a very easy problem. Thank you mate!!